# HP Laserjet network printing problems

Tags: printing, home-networking, network-printer, laser-printer, hp-laserjet

I have the excellent HP Laserjet 1536dnf printer MFP in my office, and recently decided to order another one for my little network at home. The new one is experiencing problems, however, and when I took it back for checks, it worked in the IT Support's office network just fine. So, I was left with a few possibilities. Here is the problem:

- The printer takes ages printing PDF files, even small files. As if there is an issue with spooling, which makes it too slow. Then, sometimes, it would print our random samples of the pages of a previously-printed file, just out of the blue. Also, sometimes it prints the first page of a file many times, while missing other pages (even though I only asked for 1 copy!).
- The IT guy suggested trying a different programme to print PDF. So, instead of using Adobe Acrobat, I installed another free PDF viewer, but the problem persists.
- I suspected some issues in my local network (router settings, firewall, port issues, etc) but I wouldn't know how to check this properly.
- My PC is Windows 8.1 with latest driver from HP, and all PCs on the network are Windows 7 or 8, and they have same experience. The network is wired through the a WiFi router.

Could you please assist?

Comment: A possible thing to try when printing a PDF is to go into 'Advanced' settings of the print dialog and select 'Print as image' to see if this produces better performance results...

Comment: @Big I tried this, and even tried low resolutions, but the problem persists.

Answer (score 1):

Try deleting `temp`, `log`, `prefetch`, `recent` folders from the system. This had help me as well.

Other way is to go by using  PCL 5 driver on printserver. has less options (i.e. no 1200 dpi fast-res), but works. Print jobs take 8 to 10 seconds from clients.